# File download function not working in Django views.py

Tags: python, django, xlsxwriter

[supporting.html]

```
<a href="/supporting/download/"><button type="button">Download File</button></a>
```

[supporting/urls.py]

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns =[
    path('supporting/download/',views.download),
    ...
    ]
```

[supporting/views.py]

```
def download(request):
    output = io.BytesIO()
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    merge_format = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'valign': 'vcenter'})

    supportings = Supporting.objects.filter(is_deleted='0') \
        .annotate(date_str=Cast(TruncDate('in_date'), CharField())) \
        .values_list('date_str', 'date_str', 'study_name',
                 'register_number', 'person_name', 'person__no', 'date_str', 'kinds', 'teacher', 'comment', 'technician')

supportings = pd.DataFrame.from_records(supportings)
supportings = supportings.rename(columns={0: 'Days',
                                          1: 'Date',
                                          2: 'Study name',
                                          3: 'Register Number',
                                          4: 'Name',
                                          5: 'No',
                                          6: 'Time',
                                          7: 'Kinds',
                                          8: 'Teacher',
                                          9: 'Comment',
                                          10: 'Technician'})

for supporting in supportings['Days'].unique():
    # find indices and add one to account for header
    u = supportings.loc[supportings['Days'] == supporting].index.values + 1

    if len(u) < 2:
        pass  # do not merge cells if there is only one supporting Days
    else:
        # merge cells using the first and last indices
        worksheet.merge_range(u[0], 0, u[-1], 0, supportings.loc[u[0], 'Days'], merge_format)


workbook.close()
output.seek(0)

supportings.set_index(supportings.columns[:-1].tolist()).to_excel('success.xlsx')
```

The above code works normally in Jupyter notebook and the file is downloaded. However, when I run the above code in Django, there is no return value, so "The view supporting.views.downloaddidn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead." An error occurs.

So, I deleted the to_excel method and added the code as below. However, the file cannot be downloaded. No event occurs..

```
supportings.set_index(supportings.columns[:-1].tolist())

filename = 'Supporting_List.xlsx'
try:
    filename.encode('ascii')
    file_expr = 'filename="{}"'.format(filename)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    file_expr = "filename*=utf-8''{}".format(quote(filename))

response = HttpResponse(output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; ' + file_expr

return response
```

If anyone knows a solution, please help.

Comment: Can you paste the full view code that you have now?

Comment: The code related to the download function has been pasted. If you are talking about the entire code, the amount of code is huge. Maybe any additional code you need to solve? First of all, thank you for checking it.

Comment: Try to use FileResponse instad of HttpResonse
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, instead of opening a saved file, I would like to be able to download it immediately and check it by clicking a button.